# PHP - Script using imagepng won't save file and then display it

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to load an image, edit it, save it and then display it from a script that is called within IMG tags. The script works if I want to just display the image and it does save the image. But it won't save it and then display it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $file_location = "test.png";
    if (file_exists($file_location)) {
        $img_display = @imagecreatefrompng($file_location);

        // This section of code removed as doesn't affect result

        imagepng($img_display, $file_location);
        chmod($file_location, 0777);
        imagepng($img_display);
        imagedestroy($img_display);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check chmod function - does php have permissions to write ( and change permissions ) for file? Thus if php can write - it can't change mode in the most of cases

Comment: Turn on error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` and remove your `header()` line to see the errors.

Comment: Also, don't use @ to suppress error messages. Especially during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and checks if your folder has permission to save the image. chmod 777 on it for sure.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $file_location = "test.png";
    if (file_exists($file_location)) {
        $img_display = imagecreatefrompng($file_location); // Create PNG image
        $filename = $file_location + time(); // Change the original name
        imagepng($img_display, $filename);   // Saves it with another name
        imagepng($filename);                 // Sends it to the browser
        imagedestroy($img_display);          // Destroy the first image
        imagedestroy($filename);          // Destroy the second image
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($img_display);
$contents = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($file_location, $contents);
echo $contents;
imagedestroy($img_display);
```

Comment: If the OPs version doesn't work this won't do either.

Comment: If you don't understand the question then ask for clarification in a comment.